# run matlab m file & provide parameter from windows 7 scheduler

Tags: windows, matlab, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I wish to run a matlab m file from my windows 7 scheduler.

I can run a matlab m file that takes no parameters using the line below

```
-r my_matlab_function,exit
```

If I had a matlab function that was expecting a simple text parameter is there a way to also schedule the function to run via the windows 7 scheduler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use this:

   ```
   matlab -r "functionName input1 input2"
   ```

   Note that the inputs are interpreted as text. This is called [**command syntax**](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html). For example, issuing this command from a DOS window

   ```
   matlab -r "find [2 3]"
   ```

   produces

   ```
   ans =
        1     2     3     4     5
   ```

   because `[2 3]` is interpreted as an array of five `char`s, all of which are non-zero.
2. You may also use [**function syntax**](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html):

   ```
   matlab -r "find([2 3])"
   ```

   which produces

   ```
   ans =
        1     2
   ```

   as would be expected.

Comment: I can't get it to work. So in the windows scheduler in the add arguements text box I have the following... -r myfunction myparameter,exit This does not work though in matlab the message was not enough parameters supplied. I'm trying to provide a string as a parameter

Comment: I tried putting speach marks round "myfunction myparameter" but then it doesn't even launch matlab

Comment: working now, so I just put myfunction('myparameter') and that was it, thanks for your help